# Regenerate Windows default hostnames

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, hostname

I am looking for a way to re-generate the default hostname on Windows, or to know how it is been generated to set it as hostname when it has been changed already.

Those usually looks like DESKTOP-ABCDEFG where the 2nd part is like a serial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *last* Name of a Windows Workstation (7/8/10) is saved in the registry under:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SchedulingAgent\OldName
```

The is no 'history' of all the names a workstation ever had, but this may help you in this case. (kudos to the guys of ugg.li)